# Increment input value by 10 returns NaN

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to increment an input value by 10 every time I click on a button but all i get is `NaN` in my `input` field. This is what I have done so far:

```
<button id="add">Add +10</button>
<input type="text" class="loadmoretxt" value="">
```

```js
$("#add").click( function() {    
    var loadmorevalue = parseInt($(".loadmoretxt").val(), 10) + 10;
    $(".loadmoretxt").val(loadmorevalue);
    var amounttoload = $(".loadmoretxt").val();     
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WXAvS/153/

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is on initial load the `input` has no `value` set. This means `parseInt()` returns `NaN`. You can use `||` to provide a default value of `0` in this instance:

```
var loadmorevalue = parseInt($(".loadmoretxt").val() || 0, 10) + 10;
```

Also note that you can simplify your logic by providing a function to the `val()` method:

```
$("#add").click(function () {
    $(".loadmoretxt").val(function(i, v) {
        return parseInt(v || 0, 10) + 10;
    }) 
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0oj8khgz/1/)

Comment: oh yeah.. or i could simply give a value of 10 to the inputfield and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Because when the value is empty `parseInt('', 10)` returns `NaN`

```js
$("#add").click(function() {
  $(".loadmoretxt").val(function(i, val) {
    return (parseInt(val, 10) || 0) + 10;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add +10</button>
<input type="text" class="loadmoretxt" value="">
```